# Extract the particular field value of pdf file using the apache tika

Tags: eclipse, apache-tika

I want to extract particular fields from Pdf using **Apache Tika**

```
name: Sonu Kumar
place: Chennai
company: Ramco
```

Expected output is:

> sonu kumar chennai ramco

Can any one tell me how can i achieve this using Apache Tika?

Comment: Without the code that you're using, there's not a lot we can do to help...